# Mongodb health checks via HTTP with auth enabled

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, monit

I am looking to add a check in monit to test if the server can ping the remote mongodb instance which has auth enabled. Is it possible to do a standard http check like this with mongo?

Comment: Did you try just using the configured port with a TCP check: `if failed host localhost port 27017`?

Answer (score 0):

What I have ended up doing is using the inbuilt ping inside monit like below.

```
check host <%= mongoHost %> with address <%= mongoHost %>
        if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 5 seconds
                then alert
```